# How to create a new Java project in Android Studio with no files or folders?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on my new project,but there're something wrong......I just can't new java empty project and google map project in the begining,those even don't exit on my page.

The empty project I can only create is Kotlin,but I'm not familiar with it.

What can I do?

I just search solution from web,but didn't find yet

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.